# How to make a React component reusable in terms of styling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Consider the following input component with its own scss file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./InputBox.scss";

const InputBox = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label for="fname">First name: </label>
      <input className="input-box" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputBox;
```

```
.input-box {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import InputBox from "./InputBox";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>The blue input box</div>
      <InputBox />
      <div>The green input box</div>
      <InputBox />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-blackburn-kwvso?file=/src/InputBox.scss:0-40)

The functionality is okay, my question is with the styling: say I want a green input box, it doesn't seem possible with the external SCSS file. I can pass a className as a props but I feel it's a overkill. I feel my component should not contain any style, and only apply style when using it. How can I style the same component differently?

Comment: I usually tend to style my components with a theme. If I need to be able to change say background, I would expose this value as a prop, so in different places, I can pass different colour as a background.

Comment: className/prop/parent target CSS className, whatever your usecase

Comment: @szczocik do you mean a theme for a single component or a global theme for a page or website?

Comment: It's a global theme for the whole app. I mostly use Material UI with modified themes to be fair, but that might not be suitable for every scenario.

Comment: style ur App className with `input:first-child` method .

Answer (score 0):

depending on the project I usually pass a variant prop which will determine the element's styling, so for example you have a default styling for an input field but you do have so different variants of the input with its own unique styling. So all you can do is pass a variant which will add a modifier block to your class name.

default classname = 'input'
depending on the variant the entire class name should be something like 'input input--variant-name'

all default styling go to the 'input' class name while the variant makes the changes. I feel it isn't an overkill as it is much more organized this way and with a use of a scss and css variables together you make have a very organized project structure for your styling.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using useRef hook,here is the live demo link:https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ride-j0hdp?file=/src/App.js
this way you wont be requiring any css file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pass `className` as a prop and it worked, code here:

```
const InputBox = ({ color }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label for="fname">First name: </label>
      <input
        className={"input-box-" + color}
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        name="fname"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
.input-box {
  &-blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  &-green {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>The blue input box</div>
      <InputBox color={"blue"} />
      <div>The green input box</div>
      <InputBox color={"green"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can see a few problems already:

When design a component, should I consider all possible style changes and design them as props? If yes, then every time using the component requires writing all props, which is cumbersome. If no, adding a prop requires modifying the component.